# How to determine the measurement operators of a two qubit system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I'm reviewing material for my quantum information module and I came across the following question:

"A projective measurement in the standard computational basis is to be performed on the
first qubit of a two-qubit system in the state

$$|\Psi\rangle = c_{00}|00\rangle + c_{01}|01\rangle + c_{10}|10\rangle + c_{11}|11\rangle$$

where

$$|c_{00}|^2 + |c_{01}|^2 + |c_{10}|^2 + |c_{11}|^2 = 1$$

Determine the relevant measurement operators."

Now, in my notes I've seen the following definition of a projective measurement operator:

$$\hat{M} = \sum_{m}\lambda_{m}\hat{P_{m}} $$

But I'm not sure how to obtain the projection operator P and how to apply this to a two qubit system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection operator is defined by $P_{\lambda}=|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|$, here $\lambda$ is one of the eigenstates of the system. So I believe that $|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$ are the eigenstates of two qubits system. So,
$$\hat{M}=\lambda_{00}|00\rangle\langle00|+\lambda_{01}|01\rangle\langle01|+\lambda_{10}|10\rangle\langle10|+\lambda_{11}|11\rangle\langle11|$$

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure how to represent this in a two qubit system when only measuring the first qubit. For clarification, do the eigenvalues remain the same? i.e. is $$\lambda_{00} = c_{00}$$ etc?

Comment: $c_{00}$ is not the eigenvalue. It is the coefficient of the linear combination of $|\psi\rangle$, so if you measure the eigen operator (whatever it is), the probability by which you get the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenstate $|00\rangle$ is $|c_{00}|^2$.

Comment: And I can't argure why $\lambda_{00}=c_{00}$. They are independent variables.